# What is the best way to remove an object from a list if the ID for it isn't in a list of IDs?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a list of objects with each of them having an ID. I have a second list that is just a list of media ID's. I want to remove the objects from the first list that don't match a mediaID contained in the second list. What is an efficient way of going about this? The only way I could think of was to have a nested for loop but that seems inefficient.

Here is my implementation. Note that "items" is the first list, containing MediaDetailsItem objects, with each of these objects having a specific mediaId. The second list is mediaIds.

```
List<MediaDetailsItem> shortenedList = new ArrayList<MediaDetailsItem>();
                        for(MediaDetailsItem item : items){
                            for(String id : mediaIds){
                                if(item.getMediaId().equals(id)){
                                    shortenedList.add(item);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        items.clear();
                        items.addAll(shortenedList);
```

Comment: If this code works fine, then this question is off topic on Stack Overflow, but may be good for our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JoeC Ok, thanks, I'll move it there.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, convert the `mediaIds` to a `Set`, and use the [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) method which should have an O(1) time complexity.

Additionally, using Java 8's stream APIs may not improve the efficiency, but it would probably make your code more elegant:

```
Set<String> mediaIdSet = new HashSet<>(mediaIds);
items = items.steam()
             .filter(i -> mediaIds.contains(i.getMediaId())
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```